# How to translate a slanted cylinder? ( iso-surface geometry)

Tags: geometry

A cylinder iso-surface formula is:

**$ x^2 + y^2  = 1 $**

If you want to move the cylinder 1 higher on the Y axis it  would be:

*$( x^2 + (y-1)^2  = 1 $*

It gets a bit weird with any cylinder which isn't axis aligned, a slanted cylinder, you would need to find 3 new axes $ (x_v,y_v,z_v)$ in place of $ (x,y, z)$ .

*$ x_v^2 + z_v^2 = 1 $*

So it is very confusing to place the cylinder in  $ (x,y, z)$ 3 dimensional space because I am using different vectors  $ (x_v,y_v,z_v)$...

*Question:*

Also, if I want this slanted cylinder to pass through the point P: = (1,1,1),  how is the transformation between them expressed?

How is the rotational transformation of the axes expressed? ?

This is how I get coordinates of a slanted cylinder: (using cross products and position vector)

z_v = (3,1,2) , normalized to:  ( 0.802, 0.267, 0.534).

x_v = (0.802, -0.534, 0.267)   ...a right angle of x_v.

z_v =  (0.516645, 0.214134, -0.883002)    ... dot product of V3A and V3B.

Thank you.

Comment: I found that it's a problem of interpolating rotated axes and edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, I was quitting work because of this question, else I would never solve it, and the answer came to me by way of the excellent K3dsurf forums from user Furan from Czechoslovakia...

if (y+1) + x^2 +1 = 0 moves a cylinder up on the Y axis,

then I get the distance in between the target position and the cylinder centre, and use that instead of Y.

(distance_vector + distance)^2 + (distance_tangent_vector+0)^2 +r = 0

Furan also points out that I was wrong with the axes vectors i was using on the cylinder, reversing and adding - is just for 2-D geometry. And funnily enough I think I read it here so I will go and clear that topic as well!

http://k3dsurf.s4.bizhat.com/viewtopic.php?p=994&mforum=k3dsurf#994